# Is there any Vedic reference of Lord Shiva or Lord Rudra worshipping Maa Siddhidatri to attain Siddhis?

Tags: vedas, shiva, puranas, durga, nava-durga

Here is what I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhidhatri#:%7E:text=It%20is%20believed%20that%20one,siddhis%20by%20worshiping%20this%20Goddess):

> Siddhidhatri is the ninth form of the Goddess Durga or Parvati, the
> meaning of her name is as follows: Siddhi means supernatural power or
> meditative ability, and Dhatri means giver or awarder. She is
> worshipped on the ninth day of Navaratri (nine nights of Navadurga);
> she fulfills all the divine aspirations and completes the mundane.
>
> It is believed that one side of Lord Shiva’s body is that of Goddess
> Siddhidatri. Therefore, he is also known by the name of
> Ardhanarishwar. According to Vedic scriptures, Lord Shiva attained all
> the siddhis by worshiping this Goddess.

According to Vedic scriptures, Lord Shiva attained all the siddhis by worshiping this Goddess.

If yes, then please provide me some information of that text and verses.

Comment: I edited the tags and formatted your post a little bit. Welcome to our site!